# Aligning overlayed divs in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

My first question here :)

I decide to copy recreate this front page:
www.liveform.pl

in order to practice my fresh skills on the battlefield.

Here's my starting page:
http://donkey.ninja/lf/

I'm having hard time aligning the red box with triangle, which are respectively a div(rectangle) and a p(triangle), that look like that:

```
.ontop1 {
position: absolute;
top: 94%;
bottom: 0;
left: 42%;
right:0;
z-index: 99999;
width: 300px;
height: 60px;
pointer-events:none;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 72, 1);
padding-top: 11px;
}

.triangle1 {
position: absolute;
top: 98.8%;
bottom: 0;
left: 48%;
right:0;
z-index: 99999;
width: 0;
height: 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
border-right: 40px solid transparent;
border-top: 40px solid rgba(255, 0, 72, 1);
border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

First part with "Our newest projects!" more or less holds (although the triangle does it's own magic when i start to resize)

But the i'm having problem with "Who are we?" and "What do we do?".

How do i position those elements so that they remain glued to certain place?

Comment: `.triangle { astralRecall : center;  }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I would put your red box in the `row` element that it relates to

2) I would set `position: relative` on that `row` element (that way, the red box will positions relatively to that `row`)

3) I would set a `top: -60px` on the red box (and something similar on the arrow) to move it slightly over the `row`

4) I would set a `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -150px` (half the red box's width) on the red box (and something similar on the arrow) to center it horizontally. `left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;` might also work;

Maybe it would be easier to put the arrow and the box into a single element, and change the position of that single element instead of both those elements.

EDIT: for instance: `<div class="arrow-title"><p class="ontop1">Our newest projects!</p><p class="triangle1"></p></div>`

Comment: As you said, I made one simple png out of those rectangle and triangle shapes, then set ``.row `` to ``position : relative`` and it works like a treat :)

Thank's!!

Comment: I wasn't talking about creating a png. I was talking about grouping them in a single ``div`` element. For instance: ``<div class="arrow-title"><p class="ontop1">Our newest projects!</p><p class="triangle1"></p></div>``